# Not getting results written back to excel for an CPLEX OPL model, with a new dataset

Tags: cplex, opl

I am running a model in CPLEX OPL with a new data. I have tested this model for a smaller dataset and it worked. Now in this run I am not getting any results written back to excel. Also the Problem browser is blank as seen in image below. Also to be noted is I am running this in a different computer now with higher config as the data size is much larger.

[image]

Normally I can see the parameters and the solution here. I tried reinstalling CPLEX but that did not help.

I can see that there are solutions reached in the Engine log.

Although I do not have doubt on the model as it worked with other data, yet I am putting it here for reference. To write back data to excel I use the following code (below is only part of the code)

```
solXbmt to SheetWrite(sheet,"Result!B3:E1000000");
solXbdt to SheetWrite(sheet,"Result!G3:J1000000");
solXbst to SheetWrite(sheet,"Result!L3:O1000000");
solXsmt to SheetWrite(sheet,"Result!Q3:T1000000");
SolPath to SheetWrite(sheet,"Result!X3:Z1000000");
```

In the model the sol Variables are created as below :

```
// Creating Tuples for Writing to Solution Files

tuple SolXbmt{
string b;
string m;
int t;
float x_value;
}

{SolXbmt} solXbmt = {<b, m, t, Xbmt[b][m][t]> | b in PitBlocks, m in Plants, t in TimePeriods:Xbmt[b][m][t] >0};


tuple SolXbdt{
string b;
string d;
int t;
float x_value;
}


{SolXbdt} solXbdt    = {<b,d,t, Xbdt[b][d][t] > | b in PitBlocks,  d in DumpBlocks, t in TimePeriods:Xbdt[b][d][t]>0};



tuple SolXbst{
string b;
string s;
int t;
float x_value;
}


{SolXbst} solXbst  = {<b,s,t, Xbst[b][s][t]> | b in PitBlocks,  s in Stockpiles,  t in TimePeriods:Xbst[b][s][t]>0 } ;

tuple SolXsmt{
string s;
string m;
int t;
float x_value;
}

{SolXsmt} solXsmt = {<s,m,t, Xsmt[s][m][t]> | s in Stockpiles,  m in Plants, t in TimePeriods:Xsmt[s][m][t]>0};


// create output of the paths created for each pit block : SourcePitblock, Destination, Path id, Quantity
// do sperately for pit to dump Pbd, pit to stockpile Pbs, pit to plant Pbm


tuple SolPath {
string p;
int t;
float y_value;
}

{SolPath} solPath = {<p,t, ypt[p][t]> | p in Pathid, t in TimePeriods:ypt[p][t]>0 };
```

I am not getting any output into excel. This dataset is much bigger than the data I had tested with earlier. Can you please suggest where I could have gone wrong.

It is solving and showing the number of solutions in the Engine Log, I have now tried on another computer and I could see the solution on the Problem Browser window on the left. I could see a solution there. But I wanted them written back to excel - somehow it is not writing back

Comment: Maybe this question is better suited for or.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: Hi, have you tried with oplrun ? Have you tried with a time limit or a gap ? https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/zooopl/blob/master/zoosetting1.mod Maybe your model is big and solving this model takes time

Comment: Hi Alex,Thank you for your response.  It is solving and showing the number of solutions in the Engine Log, I have now tried on another computer and I could see the solution on the Problem Browser window on the left. I could see a solution there. But I wanted them written back to excel - somehow it is not writing back